# Is there anyway to determine the public IP of a Fargate container before it becomes healthy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have an AWS Fargate container running on a public subnet. It gets auto-assigned a new public IP every time it spins up. Is there any way to determine what that IP will be before it becomes healthy?

Reason: I only have one container and do not need a load balancer, so I would like to map the DNS record directly to the IP address of the container instead of the load balancer to avoid the LB charges. All well and good, but I would also like to generate an SSL certificate with [certbot][https://certbot.eff.org/] as the container spins up. In order to do this, the DNS record has to point to the IP of the new container. I'm not sure if this is possible or not, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't directly possible.

The normal way you would associate a domain record with a container (rather than pointing the domain to a load balancer and then routing via that) is to use [ECS service discovery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-discovery.html). Currently that has the following restriction:

> The DNS records created for a service discovery service always register with the private IP address for the task, rather than the public IP address, even when public namespaces are used.

So you wouldn't be able to have that create a DNS record that points to the container(s) in the service.

One option would be to have some other thing monitor the ECS service and update the DNS record for the container automatically but it's likely there will be a level of latency involved in that which will mean you could experience short outages during deployments or task exits before the DNS record is updated to point to the new container.

An example would be to use a Lambda function and hooked up to respond to a [task start event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwe_events.html) which would update a Route53 record to point to that container's public IP address.

If you're using the [AWS CDK](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/) then the [ECS service extensions module](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/general-availability-amazon-ecs-service-extensions-for-aws-cdk/) has the [`AssignPublicIpExtension` extension](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/tree/cb1cf15e0a9a92713e71e80d0ec804c7642f1675/packages/%40aws-cdk-containers/ecs-service-extensions/lib/extensions/assign-public-ip) that will automatically create and deploy a Lambda function that will watch for these task start and exit events and update Route53 as expected.

Comment: There is apparently an ECS service extension. I was pointed to this git repo by the aws ecs people: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/%40aws-cdk-containers/ecs-service-extensions/lib/extensions/assign-public-ip/assign-public-ip.ts

I am not exactly sure how to use that extension yet, but it seems like it might be possible to publish the new IP directly to Route53 with this.

Comment: You didn't mention you were using the CDK (relevant: https://twitter.com/mattbonig/status/1432163509547122689 ;) ) but yeah that's a construct that deploys a Lambda function to do as suggested in the answer.